# Grails build-test-data Plugin - Can't Find TestDataConfig.groovy

Tags: unit-testing, grails, intellij-idea, grails-plugin

I'm trying to utilize the [build-test-data](https://github.com/tednaleid/build-test-data) plugin in my Grails (v2.4.3) app to assist with test data creation for unit testing, but while running my unit tests the plugin cannot find **TestDataConfig.groovy** to load my specified values (for unique constraint tests, etc).

---

I've installed the plugin via including it in **BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
plugins {
    ...
    test ":build-test-data:2.2.0"
    ...
}
```

I've ran the following command to create the **TestDataConfig.groovy** template, which places the file at `\grails-app\conf\`:

```
grails install-build-test-data-config-template
```

I've followed the general instructions on the [plugin wiki](https://github.com/tednaleid/build-test-data/wiki/TestDataConfig) to come up with a properly formatted file:

```
testDataConfig {
    sampleData {
        '<path>.User' {
            def a = 1
            username = { -> "username${a++}" }
        }
    }
}
```

*(Where **path** is the fully-qualified class name.)*

---

In my tests, I am using the following general format:

```
import grails.buildtestdata.TestDataConfigurationHolder
import grails.buildtestdata.mixin.Build
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

@TestFor(User)
@Build(User)
class UserSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        mockForConstraintsTests(User)

        TestDataConfigurationHolder.reset()
        user = User.buildWithoutSave()
    }

    @Unroll
    void "test #field must be unique"() {
        given: 'a User exists'
            user.save(flush: true)

        when: 'another User is created with a non-unique field value'
            def nonUniqueUser = User.buildWithoutSave()
            nonUniqueUser."$field" = user."$field"

        then: 'validation fails and the field has a unique constraint error'
            !nonUniqueUser.validate()
            nonUniqueUser.errors.errorCount == 1
            nonUniqueUser.errors.getFieldError("$field").code == 'unique'

        where:
            field << ['username', '<some other field>']
    }
}
```

But, when the test is run *(using IntelliJ IDEA)* **TestDataConfig.groovy** cannot be found via the following method in the plugin:

```
static Class getDefaultTestDataConfigClass() {
    GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(TestDataConfigurationHolder.classLoader)
    String testDataConfig = Holders.config?.grails?.buildtestdata?.testDataConfig ?: 'TestDataConfig'
    try {
        return classLoader.loadClass(testDataConfig)
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
        log.warn "${testDataConfig}.groovy not found, build-test-data plugin proceeding without config file"
        return null
    }
}
```

So the test continues on without a config file and I do not get uniquely generated data sets.

I've even tried explicitly including the file in **Config.groovy**:

```
grails.buildtestdata.testDataConfig = "TestDataConfig"
```

But, the same method in the plugin shows that `Holders.config?` is null.

---

I've looked at a few [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109136/testdataconfig-groovy-not-found-build-test-data-plugin-proceeding-without-confi) to a similar problem here on StackOverflow with nothing working in my case; I cannot figure out how to get my app to detect the presence of the **TestDataConfig.groovy** file.

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you solved this issue? Or find a workaround ?